# Webdriver for scraping articles from NYT search results

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to build a web scraper that can deal with the show more feature of the NY Times search results for a research project I'm taking part in.

I'm currently working on a driver to click the show more button until all the results pages are loaded and then I will scrape each link with beautiful soup.

The problem is that I can't get the selenium driver to click the "show more" button.

when I run the code below, the browser pops up, then closes and I get an output of "no more show more button"

I have checked that the CSS selector doesn't change with each click and have tried using an XPATH.

I'd really appreciate any insight you might have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_path = r"/Users/user_name/Desktop/chromedriver_mac64/chromedriver"
service = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/search?dropmab=false&endDate=20230321&query=covid-19&sort=best&startDate=20200101")
time.sleep(3)
while True:
    try:       
        show_more = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.css-vsuiox button'))).click()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", show_more)
        print("Show more button clicked")
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        print("No more Show more button")
        break
```

I expected the script to open the browser and click the "show more" button until every page was loaded.

The output I got was:

```
no more show more button
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. To click on the element <kbd>Show More</kbd> instead of [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.nytimes.com/search?dropmab=false&endDate=20230321&query=covid-19&sort=best&startDate=20200101")
  while True:
      try:       
          WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid=search-show-more-button]'))).click()
          print("Show more button clicked")
      except TimeoutException:
          print("No more Show more button")
          break
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Show more button clicked
  Show more button clicked
  Show more button clicked
  Show more button clicked
  Show more button clicked
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ```